# Parent And Children Relationship

Tags: java, eclipse, data-structures

I am  haveing this problem with my application and need help. I have data from the server in this form

Food  Apple  Fruit Seed   etc..

Table Chair  pen   School  et..

...

Food  Mango  Peer Melon   etc..

Reading from the left, i want to make for eg; in the first row,

Food parent of Apple

Apple parent of Fruit

Fruit parent of Seed

and if there are more data then etc..
I will itereate over the above data from the server with loop;  Example:::

```
+Food
  Apple
       Fruit
            Seed
                etc..

+Table
    Chair
        Pen
           School
                 etc..
```

The data will be shown in Tree like form in eclipse views. In the above code, "Food" and "Table" belong to the same level.
My problem is how do i begin. I have googled the whole day but can't find something that i really understand.
How can i for instance make "Food" parent and make Apple its child and then make Fruit the child of apple and so forth.

Need your help.

Thanks

Comment: Do you think it might help if you mentioned the platform?

Comment: If every node has exactly 1 descendant then it is not really a tree.

Comment: The question mentions Eclipse. So he's probably looking for a Tree in an Eclipse view, meaning he'll need SWT.

Answer (score 2):

For the beginning read some theory [Composite Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse, you will use a TreeViewer to display the tree. [This article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-TreeViewer/TreeViewerArticle.htm) explains how to use it.

You may be confused because you're finding a lot of articles talking about how to model a parent/child relationship with subclassing. You do not want that here; you want a single class that represents a node in your tree that contains a number of other instances of the same class as child nodes.